# turn video frames to streaming video

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

The server is sending video frame. I would like to use them in order to do a streaming. I wonder how I could assemble the frames to create a streaming video. So far, I could display the frames as pictures. Below is my angular code

**component angular**

```js
 getVideo() {
    interval(250).switchMap(() => this.appService.getPictures())
      .subscribe(data => {
        const file = new Blob([data], {type:'image/png'});
        this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      })
  }
```

**template html**

```html
<img div="test" [src]="url" width="400px" height="300px"/>
```

I am trying to change the picture using the frame rate of the camera. But my picture is not updated and it freezes my browser due to the high number of http requests.

What I want to achieve is to buffer the frame in order to use the `video` tag instead of the `img` tag the same way I would connect to a live streaming send by a server using the `video` tag with `src` set to the `url` of the server.

Github link: https://github.com/kedevked/frameProcessing

Comment: why not just render video as well? instead of return frame image?

Comment: Because, the server is sending images, not video. `<video src ="url" ></video>` will not display anything

Comment: I don't think it'll work that way. It'll be slow and consume a lot of bandwith.  Maybe try lowering framerate. Is having another server reading these frames and convert tem back to a video an option?

Comment: Using another server for processing is not an option I could consider

Comment: @edkeveked, interesting. Can you provide api  return  image or better sample project to github?

Comment: I updated the question with the github link

Comment: A video from picture frames is basically a gif which are tens or hundreds of times larger in file size than a compressed video. Video files are not simply a collection of picture frames.

Comment: @Mongoose, actually I could use frames to recreate the original video server side for instance by using ffmpeg. Now my question is about how to do the same process client side.

Comment: Why don't you use canvas?

Comment: @Tschallacka, could you please provide a code where the canvas can be used as a buffer for the videos?

Comment: http://techslides.com/demos/image-video/create.html

Comment: Thanks @Tschallacka, but I have already seen the website. On the [github](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/ffmpeg), the sources are not showing how to convert images to have a video.

Comment: Have you like.. right clicked and then view source? from line 92 ish?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167262/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-tschallacka).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of triggering http request at a certain interval of times, using websocket is better.

By displaying the images frame by frame, it gives the impression of a live video. The only thing though is that there might be latency in the network which makes the frame rate not to be constant. However, it works well for use cases where buffering the video server side could not be considered such as when we need to send data along each frame.

service using websocket

```
createStream(url) {
  this.ws = webSocket<any>(url);
  return return this.ws.asObservable()
}
```

component

```
constructor (private streamingService: StreamingService) {}
ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.getStream()
}

getStream() {
  this.streamingService.createStream().subscribe(data => {
    const file = new Blob([data], {type:'image/png'});
        this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
 })
}
```

This solution is well suited when we are sending not only image but also data along the image. In this scenario, the image needs to be sent as base64.

```
getStream() {
      this.streamingService.createStream().subscribe(data => {
            this.url = data.base64ImageData
     })
    }
```

Since the base64 encoding has a payload of 133% of the initial image, it might be costly to use it in all settings. In case the image needs to be served along with other data, the whole data can be sent as a binary. This will require encoding the data server-side and decode it client-side.
Since this might require a bit of computation, using a web-worker can be considered for not only decoding the data but also for displaying the image.

If the image is sent as a binary, using canvas for rendering will be faster

```
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageBinaryData, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the base64 have 133% increase, and not 1.33%?

Comment: thanks for spotting the mistake, I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

I see **two** problems here, that may improve this solution.

First of all, how do you know that the request will spend less than 250 milliseconds? if not, you know that switchMap will **cancel it**? Maybe **exhaustMap** or **concatMap** could fit better if you don't want to lose the current request.

The second point is that the interval(X) and the HTTP request are inside the angular zone, so they will fire change detection... This could bring you several performance issues. So you should run the interval and the request outside the zone and **detect changes manually**.

Said that I will purpose a solution like this:

```
private subscription: Subscription;
cosntructor(public ngZone: NgZone, public cd: ChangeDetectorRef){
   getVideo();
}

getVideo() {
    this.subscription = this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => 
         interval(250).pipe(exhaustMap(() => this.appService.getPictures()))
           .subscribe(data => {
              const file = new Blob([data], {type:'image/png'});
              this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
              // Do change detection in orther to actualize [url] binding
              this.cd.detectChanges();
           })
    );
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    // remember to unsubscribe from interval subscription
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

I don't think that with this code you would have much performance issues... although this type of long polling is never good, I don't think it would freeze your app. Try it and let me know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I really wants to do is to buffer the frames in order to have a video that I can use in a `video` tag.

Comment: Hi @edkeveked, given your situation, the preferred solution is to use an image tag, you can't buffer the getPictures() etc. and transofmr it in video format, although it has no sense. If you want to do that, just change your service and set some WebRTC connection or sov providing video content. Is my recommendation.
Although, try my solution, it may work well.

Comment: The code throws this error: `interval().concatMap() is not a function` . Could you please provide a working example when using a WebRTC we can fetch frame from the server and not from the device camera and then turn that into a video?

Comment: @edkeveked sorry, I forget the pipe operator.
I can't provide you an example, is too much. It means changes on server side, client side etc... check out kurento https://www.kurento.org, they have good docs and already done code in order to work with webRTC on both server and client.